# Winding number of $f$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{S^1}f^*(d\theta).$

Tags: differential-topology

> Let $f: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\}$ be a smooth map. Define the winding number of $f$ about 0 and prove that it equals $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{S^1}f^*(d\theta).$

I have no clue, except for the winding number of $f$
around 0 is just the degree of $u$, where
$$u(x) = \frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|}.$$

> **Degree.** $Y$ is connected and has the same dimension as $X$. We define the degree of an arbitrary smooth map $f: X \to Y$ to be the intersection number of $f$ with any point, $\deg(f) = I(f,\{y\}).$
>
> **Intersection number.** If $f: X \to Z$ is transversal to $Z$, $f, Z$ are appropriate for intersection theory, then $f^{-1}(Z)$ is a finite number of points, each with an orientation number $\pm 1$ provided by the preimage orientation.

Thank you~

Answer (score 3):

Hints: (1) The degree theorem tells you that if $f\colon M \to N$ is a smooth map between compact oriented $n$-manifolds and $\omega$ is an $n$-form on $N$, then
$$\int_M f^*\omega = \text{deg}(f)\int_N\omega\,.$$
(2) Show that $\displaystyle\int_{S^1} f^*d\theta = \displaystyle\int_{S^1} \Big(\frac f{|f|}\Big)^*d\theta $.

Comment: Thanks Ted. I am almost there except for I need to prove $\int_\Omega u^* d\theta = \int_{S^1} f^* d\theta$. Can I just claim they are equal? Or how can I justify it? I've been thinking of applying change of variable twice, but feel shooting with cannon. Thank you.

Comment: @Jellybean: ($\Omega$ should be $S^1$ above.) The easiest argument is a direct calculation. Note $d\theta=\dfrac{-y\,dx+x\,dy}{x^2+y^2}$ is invariant under scaling.

Comment: Thank you Ted. I've trying to think very hard, and I see if we scale $x,y$ then $d\theta$ is invariant. I also see that we can take the demoninator $|f|$ out from pull-pack and put in $\theta$ as $d \frac{\theta}{|f|}$. But this is different from scaling $x,y$, and this will yields the change of $d\theta$. Where did I understand you incorrectly?

Comment: Sadly, what you wrote doesn't make sense. There are fancier ways to do this, but just write it out carefully, using the product rule. If $f=(u,v)$, when you use the explicit formula for $d\theta$, when you pull back you should get $(-v\,du+u\,dv)/(u^2+v^2)$ plus a term with $d(1/\sqrt{u^2+v^2})$. Show that its coefficient is actually $0$.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry for having no time to write a complete answer. But I suggest you to read the definition of degree in more detail (what does it tell you about the behavior of $u$?). The wikipedia article on winding number and degree may be a good start.

Comment: I read the wiki article. I don't have much trouble when I learned winding number in complex analysis. But my question is from a differentiable viewpoint. I'll add the definition in my question, which does not make much sense to me solving this question.. thanks.

Comment: @Jellybean: The degree defined this way from differential topology is not entirely enlightening. Try to think about the homotopy type of the map $\mathbb{S}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{n}$ involved.