# The winding number of $f$ about $0$

Tags: differential-topology, solution-verification

> Let $f: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\}$ be a smooth map. Define the winding number of $f$ about 0 and prove that it equals $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{S^1}f^*(d\theta).$

According to the definition, we define the winding number of $f$ about $0$ to be
$$W(f,0) = \deg(u),$$
where
$$u(x) = \frac{f(x) - 0}{|f(x) - 0|} = \frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|}.$$

According to the degree formula, we have that
$$\deg(f) = \frac{\int_{S^1} f^* d\theta }{\int_{\mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\}} \theta}.$$

> I am particularly uncertain about this claim I made. Could someone help me take a look at it?

But the integration around $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\}$ is just $2 \pi$, hence we get the winding number of $f$ about 0 is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{S^1}f^*(d\theta).$

---

> **Winding number**
>   If $X$ is a compact, oriented, $l$-dimensional manifold and $f: X \to \mathbb{R}^{l+1}$ is a smooth map, the winding number of $f$ around any point $z \in \mathbb{R}^{l+1} - f(X)$ is defined by
>   $$u(x) = \frac{f(x) - z}{|f(x) - z|},$$
>   and set $W(f,z) = \deg(u).$
>
> **Degree Formula**
>   Let $f: X \to Y$ be an arbitrary smooth map of two compact, oriented manifolds of dimension $k$, and let $\omega$ be a $k$-form on $Y$. Then
>   $$\int_X f^*\omega = \deg(f)\int_Y \omega.$$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458583/winding-number-of-f-is-equal-to-frac12-pi-int-s1fd-theta/458736#458736.